# Hover jQuery Not Activating

Tags: jquery

When I hover over the input field, nothing happens. Chrome console returned with no bugs or errors. JQuery script is put in my code. Here is the code below.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">    

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #button1 {display: none;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    $('#form1').hover(function(){$('#button1').css("display", 

    "block");$(this).fadeIn(100);});

</script>

    <input type="text" id="form1"/>


    <input type="button" id="button1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your jQuery inside a document ready call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').hover(function(){
        $('#button1').css("display", "block");
        $(this).fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TBY8B/)**

Answer (score 1):

Change it from

```
$('#button1').css("display", "visible");
```

To

```
$('#button1').css("display", "block");
```

Also, you need to wrap the whole thing inside `$(document).ready()` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form1').hover(function(){
            $('#button1').css("display", "block");
            $(this).fadeIn(100);
            }
        );
    });

</script>
```